# Is it possible to animate elements inside StackLayout?

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, user-experience

Here, I provide a rough scheme of my layout and what it looks like:

[image: le rough scheme]

I want to add the following functionality: at first, I want the password label and entry to be invisible and the `submit` button to be at it's place. When the user will enter a valid username, the submit button should slide down and the password label/entry should appear (and reverse this animation if the username is invalid again). What I figured out, is that I should put a white box over password label/entry, change its opacity from 0 to 1 and slide the `submit` button by password label/entry height. Notice, that the submit button should be over the password label/entry, because when sliding, it's possible that password label/entry will overlay the submit button.

My question is: (1) is it possible to do using the StackLayout, using the scheme I'm using now and if no, (2) how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the IsVisible property coupled with Animations like FadeIn, Easing, etc

Comment: so, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. Try out yourself with some code, and if you get stuck we can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

First of all in order the button to move around the page, you should have an absolutelayout. So wrap everything in an `AbsoluteLayout`

I would set the initial `Scale="0"` for the password entry. So when the user gets valid

Here is the Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ThesisSFA.Pages.Page1">
  <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">
      <Label Text="User:"></Label>
      <Editor x:Name="EditorUser" Text="" WidthRequest="100"></Editor>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout x:Name="StackPass" Orientation="Horizontal" Scale="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.6,-1,-1">
      <Label  Text="Pass:"></Label>
      <Editor Text="" WidthRequest="100"></Editor>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonSubmit" Text="Submit" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.6,-1,-1"></Button>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And the code Behind

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            EditorUser.Completed += async (sender, args) =>
            {                    
                var rect = new Rectangle(ButtonSubmit.X, ButtonSubmit.Y + 50, ButtonSubmit.Width, ButtonSubmit.Height);
                await ButtonSubmit.LayoutTo(rect, 400, Easing.CubicIn);
                await StackPass.ScaleTo(1, 400, Easing.SinIn);
            };
        }
    }
```

This should give you an idea how to proceed

Comment: you mean substitute the main stack layout with absolute layout?

Comment: Yes exactly and set each control with an absolute position